# Does xadmin support scaling and queuing?

Tags: oracle

And when I say Scaling and Queuing, I mean it in the sense of the following article:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/04/04/scaling-and-queuing-powershell-background-jobs/

Comment: Does xadmin [refer to this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E62107_01/xoffice/index.html)?

Comment: @alex yes it does.